# PLSQL Oracle Trigger that sums amount in rows by id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have tables like this:

Shippings table:

```
ProducernName| ... |Amount
A            |...  |1
B            |...  |2
A            |...  |5
C            |...  |3
C            |...  |5
```

and another table of Producers:

```
Name|...| Shipped Amount
A   |...|  NULL
B   |...|  NULL
C   |...|  NULL
```

The idea is to make a trigger that sums the shipped amount from Shippings table for every producer and update it on the Producers table after any change (UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT)
if the trigger works the Producers table would look like this:

```
Name|...| Shipped Amount
A   |...|  6
B   |...|  2
C   |...|  8
```

What i tried is to find the summation of the amount and save it in a variable that i declared but i dont know if im in the right thinking direction and how to insert the sum in the right row in Producers table..

```
CREATE TRIGGER SumShippedTrigger
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
OF amount
ON SHIPPINGS
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
        producerShippedAmount NUMBER(10);
        producer VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
        SELECT SUM(amount) INTO producerShippedAmount 
        FROM Shippings
        WHERE producer= :NEW.producer;


    producer:= :NEW.procuder;
    END;
```

/

if anyone can help me i'll be thankful! :)

Comment: Design Rule #2749: Don't Store Summarized Data. You'll spend the rest of your career figuring out why it's wrong. Instead, summarize the data when you need it - then it will be right, at least momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a trigger for this?  Is the data so large that a simple aggregation is not feasible:

```
select producer, sum(amount)
from shippings
group by producer;
```

You can easily look this up for a single producer (using `where`) and make this more efficient using an index.

If you do use a trigger, I would say that normally the approach is to *incrementally* change the summation:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SumShippedTrigger
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF amount
    ON SHIPPINGS
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE producers
        SET amount = COALESCE(amount, 0) + COALESCE(:new.amount, 0) - COALESCE(:old.amount, 0)
        WHERE producer = COALESCE(:NEW.producer, :OLD.producer);
END;
```

Although your approach is logically correct, it does more work than necessary and will probably result in a mutating table trigger error.

Comment: A slight modification to @Gordon code is required. The trigger fires on DELETE and then :new.<column> is null. So the where clause needs to also coalesce on them.  " WHERE producer = coalesce(:NEW.producer;:Old.producer)

Comment: @Belayer . . . Good catch.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply!
However i tried your method but nothing changed on my amount row in the Producers table (it is still null after inserting all the values to the table)

Comment: @Ian . . . Something seems wrong with that.  If the names match, then the value should at least change to `0` rather than `NULL`.  It sounds like the trigger is not being called.  Or, the matching criteria does not produce an actual match.

Comment: @Ian: did you COMMIT the changes?

Answer (score -1):

In order to the following tables:

Shippings table:

```
ProducernName| ... |Amount
A            |...  |1
B            |...  |2
A            |...  |5
C            |...  |3
C            |...  |5
```

and another table is Producers:

```
Name|...| Amount
A   |...|  NULL
B   |...|  NULL
C   |...|  NULL
```

You can declare a trigger on the `producers` table like this:

```
create or replace trigger trg_producers 
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE
    ON producers
    FOR EACH ROW 
declare 
pragma autonomous_transaction;
producerShippedAmount number(10):=0;
begin

SELECT SUM(amount) INTO producerShippedAmount 
        FROM Shippings
        WHERE ProducernName = :NEW.Name;

:new.amount := producerShippedAmount;


end trg_producers;
```

It is necessary to mention that **pragma autonomous_transaction** must be declared

Comment: Triggers fire when we execute DML against their owning table. This trigger only updates PRODUCERS.AMOUNT when the PRODUCERS record is changed. That clearly is not the OP's intent: they want to update the PRODUCERS table **when the SHIPPERS table is updated**.

Comment: Ok, this way is correct in order to change the PRODUCERS table as same as changes of SHIPPERS table, so which of them is suitable for you depends on your business

Comment: Even you can reach your goal without using trigger. I suggest you can handle it in server side istead of using trigger. Using trigger is not suitable solution

Comment: When you say "server side" what do you mean? The database server can be considered  "server side", so what are you proposing?